# Results SQL results from Grails controller to dropdown list box

Tags: sql, grails, groovy

I am doing a query on a database and trying to return the list to a dropdown list box.  I'm not getting any errors, but I am not getting any results.  When I run the SQL I know it should return values, but I probably have something messed up on the controller or view side.  Any help appreciated.

Controller -

```
 import groovy.sql.Sql

 class V1Controller {
    def dataSource

    def index() { 
       def nameList = {
          def db = new Sql(dataSource)
          def results = db.rows("SELECT NAME FROM MIT_TEST_NAME")
          //results.each{row -> log.debug .name}
          [results:results]
       }        
    }
 }
```

View -

```
Test Name: <g:select name="p_project_name" from="${results}" />
```

Also, is there any good way to see what my controller SQL query is returning?

In addition to the way Joshua showed, I was also able to get it working this way.  Now I have two options of doing this! -

```
Test Name: <g:select name="p_project_name" from="${results?.NAME}" noSelection="${['null':'Select One...']}" />
```

Comment: What happended to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474623/sql-query-result-not-displaying-in-grails-view ?

Comment: The most trivial way to see what is happening a `println results` where your (broken?) commented log is.  Beside that, you could use the debugger from your IDE.

Comment: This is regarding a dropdown list box.  The other one is regarding a table.

Comment: Did the other answer help? Did it solve your issue with the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your results are not showing up in the select list is because you haven't told the tag how to find the appropriate value. The `results` is a `List<GroovyRowResult>`, so you will need tell the tag what column from the results you want to use:

```
<g:select from="${results}" optionKey="NAME" optionValue="NAME" />
```

You can read more about the g:select tag in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html).